# Hidden header on blog post

Tags: wordpress

How to show the header section on my blog post? Its completely hidden from the article

https://miorix.com/what-is-vps

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `get_header();` at the top of the article page template?

Are we assuming this is a custom theme you are creating from scratch?, if this is the case, take a look at the WP [Theme Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/), specifically maybe [this section](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/post-template-files/#single-php).

Documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/